# How to add modal in AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

How can we add modal boxes in amp pages since we cannot call external css or bootstrap scripts? i have tried using bootstrap in amp pages but amp validators fails it since we cannot call external css scripts in amp pages!

Answer (score 5):

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Font example</title>

   <script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>

  <link rel="canonical" href="notification.html" >
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>

  <style amp-custom>

    .lightbox {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .lightbox h1 {
      color: white;
    }
    button.lightClick {
        background: orange;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        min-height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: -48px;
        margin-top: 350px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success],  
        form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error] {
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
    form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success] {
        color: green;
    }
    form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error] {
        color: red;
    }
    form.amp-form-submit-success.hide-inputs > input {
        display: none
    }
    .cansle {
        font-size: 26px;
        position: relative;
        right: -22px;
        /* z-index: 99999; */
        font-family: sans-serif;
        margin: -25px auto;
        /* opacity: 0.9; */
        text-align: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: orange;
    }
    .setUpForm {
        /* margin-top: 96px; */
        max-width: 450px;
        margin: 150px auto;
        min-height: 350px;
        padding: 30px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        /* color: black; */
        margin: middle;
    }
    .setUpForm h2 {
        color: orange;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 28px;
    }
    .setUpForm form input {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 32px;
        padding: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
    }
    input.button.button-primary {
        /* text-align: center; */
        /* margin: 5px; */
        width: 140px;
        color: #fff;
        background: orange;
        border: 1px solid orange;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="lightClick" on="tap:my-lightbox"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0">
    Subscribe
  </button>

  <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay">
    <div class="lightbox">
      <div class="setUpForm">
        <div class="cansle" on="tap:my-lightbox.close"
          role="button"
          tabindex="0">X</div>
        <h2>Subscribe and get 20% off on your first order</h2>
        <form method="post"
          action=""
          target="_top">
          <input type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name..."
            required>
          <input type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email..."
            required>
          <input type="submit"
            value="Subscribe"
            class="button button-primary">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </amp-lightbox>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if it is not useful then ping me on my mail id i will give you another solution

Comment: Is there any possible way to display the modal popup on Page load?

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: @Raji did you find out a solution

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi there is no way to add modal popup on page load because AMP project is a light weight process so if u are adding modal on page load it reduces the page speed. so there is no provision to add on page load.