# modal in same window and redirection in new window on href click using css only

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I am working on AMP complaint pages which do not allow to write java script except its predefined tags, so i must have to use css for this purpose.

i need to open a modal pop up href click and open href link url in new window.

tried some tricks like using checkbox with label, but not working in my case.

```
    <label for="modal-1">this</label>
    <input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="modal">
    <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-1"></label>
<div class="modal__inner">
     <label class="modal__close" for="modal-1"></label>
     <h2>Caaaats FTW!</h2>
     <p><img src="" alt="" />Aliquam in sagittis nulla. Curabitur euismod diam eget risus venenatis, sed dictum lectus bibendum. Nunc nunc nisi, hendrerit eget nisi id, rhoncus rutrum velit. Nunc vel mauris dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam fringilla quis nisi eget imperdiet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

click on href --> modal pop up + link open in new tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine a link and a button. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495580/how-to-add-modal-in-amp-page) they explain how to create a lightbox (modal) on the page.

I have made the following changes:

1. Replace their button to add a new window link:

   `<button class="lightClick" on="tap:my-lightbox"
         role="button"
         tabindex="0">
       <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
     </button>`
2. Add styles to keep the same design:

   `button a {
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
   }`

The whole output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Font example</title>

   <script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>

  <link rel="canonical" href="notification.html" >
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>

  <style amp-custom>

  button a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

.lightbox {
         background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .lightbox h1 {
      color: white;
    }
    button.lightClick {
    background: orange;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -48px;
    margin-top: 350px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    cursor:pointer;
        z-index: 9999;
}
 form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success],
          form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error]{
            margin-top: 16px;
        }
        form.amp-form-submit-success [submit-success] {
            color: green;
        }
        form.amp-form-submit-error [submit-error] {
            color: red;
        }
        form.amp-form-submit-success.hide-inputs > input {
            display: none
        }
.cansle {
    font-size: 26px;
    position: relative;
    right: -22px;
    /* z-index: 99999; */
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: -25px auto;
    /* opacity: 0.9; */
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: orange;

}
.setUpForm {
    /* margin-top: 96px; */
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: 150px auto;
    min-height: 350px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    /* color: black; */
    margin: middle;
}
.setUpForm h2 {
    color: orange;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.setUpForm form input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
}
input.button.button-primary {
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* margin: 5px; */
    width: 140px;
    color: #fff;
    background: orange;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
 <button class="lightClick" on="tap:my-lightbox"
      role="button"
      tabindex="0">
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Subscribe</a>
  </button>


  <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox"
      layout="nodisplay">
    <div class="lightbox">

    <div class="setUpForm">
    <div class="cansle" on="tap:my-lightbox.close"
        role="button"
        tabindex="0">X</div>
    <h2>Subscribe and get 20% off on your first order</h2>
     <form method="post"
      action=""
      target="_top">
    <input type="text"
        name="name"
        placeholder="Name..."
        required>
    <input type="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="Email..."
        required>
    <input type="submit"
        value="Subscribe"
        class="button button-primary">
  </form>
  </div>
    </div>
  </amp-lightbox>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This will open a Modal on click suscribe, and take you to stackoverflow in a new window.

*Note: run it in a local file otherwise it would complain that "localStorage" is not supported.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the destination of a link in CSS. You have to add the `target`-attribute to the `<a>`-tag.

You have to use

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"></a>
```

for a new tab/window.

Also, opening a modal can most likely only be done with JavaScript. It might be possible using CSS selectors but it would be extremely hard to do.

Comment: can you provide hints, how can i achieve it via css

Comment: I am not an expert but I think if you would include it, it would be extremely hacky and probably won't work on every browser. I would recommend you contact the webmaster and ask whether you can edit the html. @ArbazKhan