# Is there any possible way to add the modal popup on Page load for AMP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amp-html

I want the modal popup in AMP page on Page load. while using amp-lightbox, I would do the modal popup but it can be done by clicking the button. I want this by on page load. How can be done this?

Comment: You could check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495580/how-to-add-modal-in-amp-page) that can solve your issue. It has a code you can use using `amp-lightbox`. Then try to integrate the process on lightbox popup gallery like this sample in this [blogpost](http://visuallightbox.com/rq/automatically-open-the-lightbox-popup-upon-opening-the-page-r.html).

Comment: @Raji you can not load popup or anything on load, amp structure and layout create like this.

Comment: any solution to this?